How to remove the smudges from the stamp tool on a picture (Adobe Photoshop)?
I'm trying to remove lettering from a billboard with a stamp tool. But, in doing so, there are still noticeable smudges of a darker or lighter color on the picture than there should be.
Image: https://imgur.com/a/KjhnmZI
How do I make the color overlay evenly across the entire length of the billboard, with no smudges? Perhaps I should use some other technique?

The stamp tool merely clones from the source. You are picking up light/dark areas when you clone. More precision, cloning smaller areas at a time, with a smaller brush, would help.
